# How to log into facebook with robobrowser?

Tags: python, facebook, robobrowser

This is my code:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 1;\en-    US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6')
browser.open('https://www.facebook.com/')
# Get the signup form
form = browser.get_form(id='login_form')
form['email'].value = 'my_user'
form['pass'].value = 'my_pass'
browser.submit_form(form)
```

My error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ResponseNotReady('Request-sent',))

Answer (score 1):

Well, this works :

```
    browser = RoboBrowser(
        history=True,
        user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0'
    )
    browser.open('https://m.facebook.com')
    form = browser.get_form(id='login_form')

    form['email'].value = user
    form['pass'].value = password

    browser.submit_form(form)
```

Comment: It is showing me the error : `robobrowser.exceptions.Invalid Submit Error` while using the same code as you stated.

Comment: well... I guess that since 2015, the API may have changed... I'll look in my old scripts if I find something and I'll update this answer accordingly if I do

Comment: Thanks it would help me a lot. @yota